# Why is everything getting cast to int?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table in a sql server database with a `year` column of type `shortint` and a `qtr` column of type `tinyint`. When this table is imported with entity framework, the types of the corresponding properties are `short` and `byte` as expected. Now when I try and run a query like this:

```
query = myTable.Where(a => a.year > qyear || (a.year == year && a.qtr >= qqtr));
```

Where `qyear` and `qqtr` are again `short` and `byte` respectively, if I look at the SQL generated (using `myContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(s);`) I see this:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[year] as [year],
    [Extent1].[qtr] as [qtr],
    /* a bunch of other fields */
    FROM [dbo].[myTable] as [Extent1]
    WHERE (( CAST( [Extent1].[year] AS int) > @p__linq__0) OR 
    (((( CAST( [Extent1].[year] AS int) = @p__linq__1) AND 
    ( NOT (( CAST( [Extent1].[year] AS int) IS NULL) OR 
    (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))) OR (( CAST( [Extent1].[year] AS int) IS NULL) 
    AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[qtr] AS int) >= @p__linq__2)))
```

Why is everything getting cast to an `int` for comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is everything getting cast to an int for comparisons?

Because that's what the C# language defines. It doesn't define any operators on `byte`, `short` etc - they're all promoted to `int` before anything happens. That gets propagated to expression trees too. As an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<byte, byte, bool>> func = (x, y) => x > y;
        Console.WriteLine(func);
    }
}
```

That prints

```
(x, y) => (Convert(x) > Convert(y))
```

and if you look at the IL, you'll see that the `Convert` calls are effectively

```
Convert(xParameterExpression, typeof(int))
```

and

```
Convert(yParameterExpression, typeof(int))
```

So the SQL is representing *exactly* what your C# represents... and I'd expect it to behave exactly the same way too. I would be surprised if this had any cost - any decent query optimizer is going to realize that it can just use the values as they are, without *really* converting each one in turn.

Comment: Perfect! Forced my to delete my answer. As usual Skeeted :)

Comment: Yeah me too...there ought to be a t-shirt or something :)

Comment: Ok - so that's probably not why my query is running way slower here than directly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @MattBurland: I *suspect* not... but you should use query profiling to see. Basically, try the query with the conversions in Management Studio, and then try the same query without the conversions. Maybe I'm wrong and the query optimizer really can't handle it - in which case, you could be for some fun times trying to avoid this behaviour...

Comment: @JonSkeet: A quick experiment in Management Studio doesn't seem to show any appreciable difference. I haven't tried a more indepth profiling yet, but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @MattBurland: Right. I'm not sure whether that's good or not (it would be tricky to avoid if it were the problem, but now it means you've got to look elsewhere) - but at least we know more than we did before :)